CMake: use FetchContent_Declare with a library and its dependency
With CMake, how can we use use FetchContent for two libraries (both CMake projects) libfoo and libbar, with libfoo having libbar as a dependency?
If FetchContent cannot solve this very straightforward problem, what use does it even have?
Yet, I found no information on how to tackle this. The include  and binary files for libbar are obviously present after building, and CMake allows linking from the main project, but not from libfoo if it just added via FetchContent_Declare.

The minimal example for redis++ and its dependency hiredis
Outer CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(example_job)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
add_subdirectory(main)
include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(
  hiredis
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/redis/hiredis.git
  GIT_TAG v1.2.0
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(hiredis)

FetchContent_Declare(
  redis-plus-plus
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus.git
  GIT_TAG 1.3.12
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(redis-plus-plus)

The subdirectory's ./main CMakeLists.txt contains the single line add_executable(example_job "main.cpp")
Now cmake -B build -S src -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release fails, with
CMake Error at /home/amat/build/_deps/redis-plus-plus-src/test/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_path):
3.969   Could not find HIREDIS_HEADER using the following files: hiredis

But is that in principle possible? Can I link that way, since it works for one library?
